# Salesforce REST API (PHP) - Trouble Creating 'Address' Records

Tags: salesforce

I have been creating Accounts using the REST API without issue, until it comes to creating the Address object which contains a custom field 'Address__c' which accepts an 'Address' data type.

I have been trying to submit a keyed array of all address related properties - City, Country, PostalCode etc as per their own docs regarding the Address Compound fields:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm

```
object(App\Models\Salesforce\Address)#92 (11) {
  ["Account__c"]=>
  string(18) "001Tu000002X57sIAC"
  ["Address__c"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["City"]=>
    string(6) "London"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(14) "United Kingdom"
    ["CountryCode"]=>
    string(2) "UK"
    ["PostalCode"]=>
    string(7) "W1U XXX"
    ["State"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Street"]=>
    string(22) "9999 London Square"
  }
  ["Address_Function__c"]=>
  string(7) "Billing"
  ["Address_Type__c"]=>
  string(4) "Home"
  ["Billing_Address__c"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["CDD__c"]=>
  NULL
  ["Countries__c"]=>
  NULL
  ["CurrencyIsoCode"]=>
  NULL
  ["Name"]=>
  NULL
  ["Shipping_Address__c"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["State_Province__c"]=>
  NULL
}
```

However this does not work - gives the following type of error:

```
"Cannot deserialize instance of 00N8d00000Wy5b9 from VALUE_STRING value London or request may be missing a required field"
```

It seems that others have encountered the same issue.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4GrMSAV

I have tried changing the casing of the address members to lower case as suggested, I encounter the same issue,

```
"message": "Unable to create/update fields: Address. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set."
```

The thread suggest that you send the City/Street/Country etc. properties directly as part of the Lead object (not the Address).

How can I resolve this issue?